# Visual Studio 2015 Publish to Azure Securely

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, publish

When I use the publish option out of Visual Studio 2015 to publish a website to Azure, is there a way to ensure that the publish to the host in secure; not in plain text?  Is the publish sent to azure SSL or encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the build output in Visual Studio, when you publish using Web Deploy in Visual Studio, the website binaries and other files are sent over SSL. Please look at the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Does this mean that my Azure Web App has to have an SSL certificate applied even though I'm just trying to publish via SSL to Azure because I'm not seeing an https:// publish in the build output.   I assume that's the case since it appears to be publishing over https in your output.  I actually wondered if there's some type of ftp with ssl transfer going on.

Comment: Not really. By default your web app has a `azurewebsites.net` domain and that one has a SSL certificate. If you look at the screenshot above, the code is deployed to `yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net` and that one has SSL certificate. I am not sure about the FTP though whether it is secured or not.